# "the value does not fall within the expected range" DFS error on Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, .net, dfs, dfs-r

I seem to have run into this bug while attempting to create a DFS replication group: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4049095/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-error-when-you-change

The server in question is 2012, not 2012R2. I am fully patched but thought I would try to install the "equivalent" of the patch listed for 2012R2 (which is KB4075212). So, I tried installing KB4075213, however, I receive a "the update is not applicable to your computer"

So on to the workarounds, I tried to use the DFS commands to create a replication group, however, none of the commands are recognized. I double checked, and yes, the DFS management tools are installed.

Next, I tried to uninstall .net 4.7, however, they aren’t "programs". I found out what version I have with regedit and I am on 4.7.1. I assume these are deployed through windows update but none of the KBxxxxxxx show up in the "installed updates" tab of Windows Update: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Can .net 4.7.2 and 4.7.1 be removed from command line/Powershell? Or has anyone been able to get it to work with the "fix" installed? (like I said, I believe the fix they are referring to is installed so I think their fix doesn’t work).

This server is Server2012 Datacenter and is fully patched. As it’s a production file server, it will be hard for me to schedule reboots during the week, so keep that in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows Server 2012 (regardless of flavor) .Net Framework is a Windows Update Component and **not** a Program. So you should look up that stuff under "Installed updates" by KB number. Yes, I know it's painful, but that's the way it is.. To spare you some pain, here's my notes on the issue:

Windows Server 2012 (non-R2):

- .Net 4.7 Windows Server 2012 - KB3186505
- .Net 4.7.1 Windows Server 2012 - KB4033345
- .Net 4.7.2 Windows Server 2012 - KB4054542

Windows Server 2012 R2:

- .Net 4.7 Windows Server 2012 R2 - KB3186539
- .Net 4.7.1 Windows Server 2012 R2 - KB4033369
- .Net 4.7.2 Windows Server 2012 R2 - KB4054566

Comment: Thank you for providing the KB #'s. Oddly enough, under the "View update history" section, I can find and confirm that those KB's are installed. However, under "Installed Updated" I can not find the KB #'s. Are they bundled in with other updates by chance? The "View Update History" section doesn't provide the ability to uninstall updates, but that's the only screen I can confirm they were installed at.

Comment: Numbers I've given install *The Beast* himself, they are handy to prevent its appearance. However, there were so called "security and quality rollups" for it, start here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/08/14/august-2018-security-and-quality-rollup/ that's the latest one I believe, and follow release history at the bottom to find the version actually installed.

Comment: I found the roll-up that appears to have it (4344144) and uninstalled. I will plan a reboot and cross my fingers! Thanks